# Raised 100k on a gofund.me campaign to teach a hands on electronics repair workshop for the next few years. How do I pay taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, new-york

I managed to raise 100k on a gofund.me campaign to teach a hands on electronics repair workshop. This amount lets me do workshops at least twice a month for the next 3+ years. Since I received this funding this year, do I pay taxes on this 100k this year?

But, since I haven't done the class in the future yet. I can't write off expenses for the future. I'm not sure how taxes work in this case as this is technically funding for the future and I don't know what my real expenses are yet. How do you space this earned income into future years?

Comment: Is this a non-profit venture or a for-profit business?  That's probably the best place to start.

Comment: Oh this is for new york and yes its for a business. I have an LLC that I file together with my personal taxes every year.

Comment: if something like this happens, it should go in to a *corporate entity*.  that entity then pays for things, pays your LLC, and so on.

Comment: duplicate ?  https://money.stackexchange.com/a/15527/41786

Comment: @Fattie: LLC is passthrough for tax by default but can elect to be treated as corporation. OP isn't clear on what 'fil[ing] together' means; that could be 1040 + 1120[-S]. Although it would matter here only if the corporation is using accrual accounting, which is not automatic or generally required.

Comment: hi @dave_thompson_085 "LLC is passthrough for tax by default but can elect to be treated as corporation", yes, an excellent point, sorry; you're quite right of course.  I should have written something like *"Your own LLC is just a pass through entity; you will need an actual corporate entity."*

Comment: so i need a real corporate entity and my LLC isn't one? like what?

Comment: This is a great question, and I hope it gets a great answer. However, no matter what kind of answer you get here, you need to go to see an actual accountant/tax advisor who can look at all the details of your situation and help you figure out the best way to handle it.

Comment: @BenMiller Yes I understand. I just want to educate myself on my options so I know what to ask my accountant. As not all accountants are upto date on latest tax loopholes. Most just take the easy route and will just tell you to just "pay your taxes". I'm not looking for that.

Comment: Is it an L3C? Whose EIN/SSN got used when setting up the GoFundMe campaign?  Did you get a 1099 or W-2 from GoFundMe? Whose name was on it, yours or a company's?

Comment: I have a pass through LLC. Used the EIN from the LLC.

Answer (score 6):

**Go see an accountant.**

Not an income tax service, not your buddy who does taxes on the side, an honest-to-goodness CPA who works for small businesses.

There are too many unknowns to get a useful answer from this crowd.

- Do you have ongoing expenses (i.e. rent for a shop)?
- How much equipment do you own and what do you have to purchase?
- Do you owe specific goods or services to the givers?
- Are the givers deducting the donations from their income?
- Do you already have known plans and/or commitments?
- Do you have a regular schedule or is it unknown at the time?
- Are you paying yourself a salary or paying yourself as training is delivered?

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh this is for new york and yes its for a business. I have an LLC that I file together with my personal taxes every year. –

Sounds, to me, like your business just received $100,000 in revenue.  Better get to work.